# Importing data into Neo4j from S3 bucket using authentication

Tags: amazon-s3, neo4j, load-csv

I'm new to Neo4j and testing it on EC2 server, to see if we could use it for storing our ~1.5 nodes and their connection (currently using a Redshift).

I want to load all the data from Redshift to the Neo4j DB. I also work a lot with EMRs and usually storing most of my data on S3.

Is there any way to include AWS authentication information when I try importing data to Neo4j from S3 if the S3 location isn't public? Is there any other way to do so?

Thanks